# button, iframe, div, play, stop - help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to make a button to load a div with an iframe.

For example: when pressing "play", it opens a div with an `iframe` and when pressing "play" again, this iframe is closed (I do not want it to be playing in the background).

I want to place YouTube videos on my site!

```
<center>
  <iframe width="450px" height="60px" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0 id="test456" src="http://escuchala.com/includes/youtube.php?id=<?php echo $video['id']['videoId'];?>"></iframe>
</center>
```

Comment: I need to make a button that calls an iframe and another that disappears it

Comment: There is no `button` code show to attempt show/hide the `iframe`. Have you tryed something?

Comment: do not. that's why I need help!

Comment: I have made several codes but none of them works for me! and I'm almost crazy

Comment: Missing an ending quote after `framespacing="0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by opening and closing the video, but I guess you just want to make it appear or disappear. You can do this by changing the element's `display` property. To stop a video, playing in an `iframe`, just set the source again:

```
video.src = video.src;
```

Besides, the `center`-tag is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Use CSS instead:

```
#video {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hence, you probably want a behavior like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cajqfbd6/).

### EDIT

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/eov8gpfd/) should fit to your needs.

Comment: It is exactly what I want. thank you for understanding

but there is an error!
It does not open after it's closed which is one of the things I want!

Comment: make a button to open it. and one to close it!
as (Play) and another to close the video (stop)

Comment: Okay, I adapted it. See my edit.

Comment: you are the best.!!!!!